# Convert Line Render to 3d Mesh with Collider Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, gameobject

I have looked around and haven't found a working answer, so your help would be appreciated!

Currently with this script, the line creates a blank mesh filter. The closest I got to was having offset simple block that does not follow the shape mesh at all. I need this in order to be able to have the shapes drawn with the line trigger sounds on collision

```
GameObject go = new GameObject($"LineRenderer");
goLineRenderer = go.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();  

 Mesh lineBakedMesh = new Mesh(); //Create a new Mesh (Empty at the moment)
go.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();  
go.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = lineBakedMesh;
 goLineRenderer.BakeMesh(lineBakedMesh,Camera.main, true); //Bake the line mesh to our mesh variable
     go.AddComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = lineBakedMesh; //Set the baked mesh to the MeshCollider
     go.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().convex = true; //You need it convex if the mesh have any kind of holes
```

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Comment: Okay, but I'm using unity

Comment: Yes, this the tag `unity3d`. But [unityscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unityscript) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now as the tag description mentions. Your code is clearly `c#` not `unityscript`

Comment: oh right thanks for informing me.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to me that you are creating a new `LineRenderer` component but you are not setting any points on it to form a line.

You can use [`LineRenderer.SetPosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPosition.html) to set individual points or [`LineRenderer.SetPoisitons`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.SetPositions.html) to assign them all in one go after setting the correct target amount of [`LineRenderer.positionCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer-positionCount.html). Especially if you are going to update these points on runtime.

Otherwise it might be easier to simply already add and configure the component according to your needs via the [Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html).

---

Since you say you already configured a `LineRenderer` via the Inspector: Do you maybe rather want to use

```
goLineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
```

in order to get the component that is already added to the same GameObjects as this script?

Comment: Hi, the line render is setup already, but the issue is converting the line to a collidable game object

Comment: Well we can't tell .. in your code you don't ... There you are adding a new component

Comment: When "Currently with this script, the line creates a blank mesh filter." I'm using GitHub Script that already creates the line successfully. It might not be clearly written sorry. The issue is with generating a mesh filter & collider that follows the Linerenderer lines made

Comment: Please add the code you are actually using then. The one you posted creates a new added LineRenderer and there is no evidence of any added points. As mentioned, could this be the issue and you rather want to use `GetComponent`?

Comment: Wait. Do you see the code stating, goLineRenderer.BakeMesh(lineBakedMesh,Camera.main, true); etc.... Please check the question again.

Comment: I do .. but I also see your code stating that you do `GameObject go = new GameObject($"LineRenderer");
goLineRenderer = go.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();` which is creating a new GameObject with a new LineRenderer without assigning any points

Comment: Oh Okay, this just an a snippet from https://github.com/dilmerv/ARDraw  inside the AR Line.cs https://github.com/dilmerv/ARDraw/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Managers/ARLine.cs then inside "public void AddNewLineRenderer" function

Comment: Again please add the exact code you are using in your project. Are you 100% positive that you have a valid Line and are using the `BakeMesh` on the same `LineRenderer` reference?